# Pods unable to update or install - Dart/Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement firebase and for that I have to update the pods. However, when I type pod repo update in the console, it just does nothing... it just shows my "Updating spec repo 'trunk'" and then it shows my prompt. And if I type pod install into the console it shows:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/tlobry/Desktop/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first.

 #  from /Users/tlobry/Desktop/Podfile:16
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
 >      raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
 #    end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: flash_chat
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0<3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - images/
```

and this is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've tried in the past to fix Pod install issues:

Remove podfile.lock from the ios folder

```
rm Podfile.lock
```

Run pod install again

You may also try changing your Podfile to
platform :ios, '10.0'

Comment: Have you tried this solution?
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9757

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute `flutter pub get`